# Importing a spring config file via EL in spring XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Import the spring xml in another spring xml the location of the xml file will be dynamically construct using EL in spring.
I tried as below. Its not working.

`<import resource="../core/#{systemProperties['test.demo.enable']  eq 'true'?'XXXX':'YYYY' }/my-context.xml" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but it could work if you build the path completly in EL:

```
<import resource="#{'../core/'.concat(systemProperties['test.demo.enable']  eq 'true'?'XXXX':'YYYY').concat('/my-context.xml')}" />
```

It works in one of my spring security intercept URL definition, but i have not testet it with your case.

Comment: If we used this #{ } it first try to load the beans in the XML so its getting, not importing the xml first. But I have dependencies in the importing XML. So its throw null pointer exception.